# Searching a JSON stored in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have some data stored in my DB in a JSON array. I need to search through this data for instances of a name. How would I do that using eloquent? Generally, I'd simply do

`User::where('name',$name)->get();`

but that just returns empty.

Comment: Don't store data in a structure like JSON that you may need to search on. It creates headaches when trying to do something like this. Why not store your data in a better more usable structure? like actually creating fields for it.

Comment: No, I'm using 5.5.47.

Comment: @mic The essence of the DB is to store scorers for a sports team. That leaves a problem when recording those who score. I've got the "score" field which stores the JSON. Other than that I could potentially have loads of fields or none.

Comment: So you use a different table to store each of the scorers and join it to you other table. For instance your would have a game table with an ID column which links to a scorer table. The each game could have 0 or many scores and this would allow you to search in the scorer table. Essentially you are trying to store a data structure in one field which is bad, it makes it difficult for people to understand and future devs will not be able to easily understand what you were thinking. Remember that a relational database is not a spreadsheet!

Comment: No @RyanVincent I have a row for a Match, then the fields relate to tries, try quantities etc. and within the fields I'd have a JSON array

Comment: If you must search on the JSON just do it something like `where('score', '"name": "<name of the player>"')` so that it matches the structure of the JSON.

Comment: Thanks @mic so you suggest having a table for each game? Wouldn't that give me LOADS of tables come the end of the season? Or am I misunderstanding you (sorry if I'm being a bit on the slow side)

Comment: The scorer table will hold scorers for all the games. You have an additional field in there called game_id (or something like that) then you can do a LEFT JOIN in the query from the game table -> scorer table. This will return all the rows that are associated with the specific game ID (if there are any).

Comment: I would go and read something like http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561 which will point you in the right direction :D

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll have a think about redesigning and I'll check that out. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great help in the comments and I will look at redesigning, but an actual answer to my questions is:

```
User::where('tries','LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
```

And this returned all instances of that name in the json arrays